# Update SharePoint field with Current Date and time

Tags: json, sharepoint

I have created a SharePoint list with a button that when you click it up updates who updated the data in the column. I can't for the life of me figure out how to insert the current date and time into the other column. I am sure I'm just missing some syntax. iv also tried [Today] . The column thats being updated is set to DateTime. Does it need to be something else?

```html
{
  "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/v2/column-formatting.schema.json",
  "elmType": "button",
  "txtContent": "Update Runbook",
  "customRowAction": {
    "action": "setValue",
    "actionInput": {
      "UpdatedBy": "@me",
      "RunbookLastUpdated": "Now ()"
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that this requirement can be achieved by integrating with Power Automate.

**Reference:**

https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/sharepoint/json-syntax-clickable-button-to-capture-record-the-time-and-date/m-p/2581811